# IsEmpty not working as expected in Pig

Tags: function, apache-pig, is-empty, latin

I have a relation  J2, which looks like (Popp,{(100)}) (Urman,{(100)}) (Sciarra,{(100)}) (Chen,{(100)}) (Faviet,{(100)}) (Gietz,{()}) (Higgins,{()}) (LAST_NAME,{()}) (Grant,{()}).... i have to test whether the bag is empty or not, so tried :S = FILTER J2 BY IsEmpty($1);.. it is getting executed successfully but the output is empty. Can anyone please guide me on this. Is there any prerequisites to use IsEmpty()?

Note:DESCRIBE J2 gives "{AA::LAST_NAME: chararray,{(int)}}"

Comment: You could also try to use `SIZE()`. Like this: `S = FILTER J2 BY SIZE($1)==0;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the explanation:
You had bags contains tuples, so in the following case: Gietz,{()} the bag itself is not empty has an empty tuple in it. So let's test the following input:

```
Urman,{(100)}
Gietz,{()}
LAST_NAME,{}
```

If you project the SIZE of the bags  you'll get the following results:

```
(Urman,1)
(Gietz,1)
(LAST_NAME,0)
```

Gietz's bag size is also 1 because it contains a tuple and it doesent matter if the tuple itself is empty.

How to do it:
(This is one working solution)

```
data = LOAD 'SO/name.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,b:bag{(val:int)});
DESCRIBE data;
a = FOREACH data GENERATE name AS name, b AS b, FLATTEN($1) AS x;
b = FILTER a BY x IS NULL;
DUMP a;
```

It dumps:

```
(Gietz,{()},)
(Higgins,{()},)
(LAST_NAME,{()},)
(Grant,{()},)
```

Input:

```
Popp,{(100)} 
Urman,{(100)}
Sciarra,{(100)} 
Chen,{(100)}
Faviet,{(100)} 
Gietz,{()}
Higgins,{()}
LAST_NAME,{()} 
Grant,{()}
```